# Django static files getting 404

Tags: django, static

Hello and thanks for your help in advance. I realize this question has been asked and answered in other placed but none of those answers are working for me.

I am new to python and django and have inherited a small webapp. I have a dev environment working on my computer with mostly unchanged code, the only changes being to the database name and password to point to my local mySQL server.

However, when I run the app, everything works except for the static files. I'm getting 404s in the console when trying to retrieve static files and js methods in static are coming up undefined.

The BASE_PATH, STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIR, STATICFILES_FINDERS are all unchanged from the currently working production code, and as far as my beginner eyes can tell are configured correctly according to the documentation and the multiple answers to this question.

Is there something that could be different about what I have installed on my computer that would be causing this? Why else would it be different between production and my local copy? Is there something I have to run to get this working?

Some settings in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'biogen.apps.BiogenConfig',
    'msm.apps.MsmConfig',
    'tracker.apps.TrackerConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'process_manager.apps.ProcessManagerConfig',
    'process.apps.ProcessConfig',
    'pfd.apps.PfdConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djangobower',
    'rest_framework',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_summernote'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'components/static'),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
]
```

Included in the templates:

```
{% load static %}
```

Thanks again in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Provide something like this:

Consider you have in your project root directory `static_files` as a source and `static` as a destination of your static files - you initially place and edit them in static_files (or any other you have):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files/js'),
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files/html'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', )
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Notice it's `STATICFILES_DIRS`, not `STATICFILES_DIR`

Then run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

to collect your static files from `static_files` to `static`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to load all the static files from Bower. All these files are present on production but not on development for some reason!

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: inspect element in browser and see the complete url of 404 elements.